# codePro junit generates in junit-4 always

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit3, codepro

I am using codePro tool to generate junit. Since I am using JDK1.4, I opted junit3 in codePro settings.

Despite me setting junit-3, the test cases are generated in junit-4 (with annotations)

The first screen shot shows that my setting shows my selection on junit-3
The second screen shot shows that test case generations are happening based on junit-4

[image: SELECTED JUNIT-3]

[image: TEST CASE GENERATED BASED ON JUNIT-4]

**Please guide me on this**

Answer (score 0):

I found it why it is happening.

Even though I opted junit-3, I was not having junit-3 jar file in my classpath and hence eclipse used junit 4 jar file from its plug-in folder

Now after including junit-3 jar file, am able to generate testcases with junit-3.